# Is it possible to specify the sql select query inside if condition

Tags: php, sql-server, if-statement

I have a query like the following:

```
mssql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRTL_PasswordSecurityQuestions where isPublished = 1 ")
```

I need to display some content when count is greater than 3. For that I have put the statement like this.

```
if(mssql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRTL_PasswordSecurityQuestions where isPublished = 1 ")>=3)
{......}
```

Is it correct way to check.Anyway its not working for me.

Comment: fetch it first. then make your comparison

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: So you mean this comparison is wrong ..right @Ghost

Comment: first assign query result into variable, and then get count of rows from variable. I dont know what `mssql_query` returns in php

Comment: @Techy yes, your basically, comparing zero to a resource

Comment: @JayBlanchard actually, its the `mssql` API, but i agree, i'd take PDO any day

Comment: Oops @Ghost ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: mssql is like mysql,but my database is sql server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly compare it inside your if condition:

```
if(mssql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRTL_PasswordSecurityQuestions where isPublished = 1 ")>=3)
{......}
```

Since it returns a result set, you need to fetch it first, after getting the count and stored, then you make your comparison:

```
$query = mssql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM PRTL_PasswordSecurityQuestions WHERE isPublished = 1";
$row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query); // fetch it first

if($row['total'] > 3) {
    // do what you have to do
}
```